# One variable, one class and two of the same function swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I have searched google for this answer for so long, until I created an account at stack overflow to ask this question.

How do you program a variable to hold a class with some variable in it then call the same function two times? Explained in the code:

```
class Persons {

var oldName = ""
var oldAge = 0
var oldGender = ""
var name = ""
var age = 0
var gender = ""

func create(_ name:String, _ age:Int, _ gender:String) -> String {

    if(age > 100) {
        print("Can't create a person with an age that is over 100!")

        return "Not created!"
    }

    if(gender == "Boy" || gender == "Girl") {

    }
    else {
        print("Gender has to be a girl or a boy!")

        return "Not created!"
    }
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.gender = gender

    self.oldName = name
    self.oldAge = age
    self.oldGender = gender

    print("You just created a \(gender) called: '\(name)' with the age of: '\(age)'!")

    return "Created!"
}

func modify(_ targetName:String, _ newName:String, _ newAge:Int, _ newGender:String) -> String {

    if(age > 100) {
        print("Can't modify a person with an age that is over 100!")
        return "Not modified!"
    }

    if(gender == "Boy" || gender == "Girl") {

    }
    else {
        print("Gender has to be a girl or a boy!")
        return "Not modified!"
    }

    if(targetName != "" && targetName == self.name) {
        self.name = newName
        self.age = newAge
        self.gender = newGender

        print("You just changed \(oldName)'s gender from: \(oldGender) to: \(gender), \(oldName)'s name from: \(oldName) to: \(name) and \(oldName)'s age from: \(oldAge) to: \(age)!")
    }
    else {
        print("Please enter a valid target name or create one!")
    }

    return "Modified!"
}

func delete(_ targetName:String) -> String {

    if(name != "" && targetName == self.name) {
        print("Deleted: \(name)!")
    }
    else {
        print("Please enter a valid target name or create one!")
    }

    return "Deleted!"
}

}

var p = Persons()
p.create("Isak", 11, "Boy")
p.create("Sanne", 7, "Girl") // Here I create another person
p.delete("Isak") // But if I say delete 'Isak' it does not delete him because I created 'Sanne' above!

/*
It would work like this

p.create("Isak", 11, "Boy")
p.delete("Isak")
p.create("Sanne", 7, "Girl")
*/
```

Please help. I have spent ages to find the answer. If you need more details just reply and I will try to explain some more.

Comment: You do not understand instantiation! You have created just one instance of person by p = Person(). Then you are only modifying properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are working with a single instance of Person. When you are doing:

```
p.create("Isak", 11, "Boy")
p.create("Sanne", 7, "Girl") // Here I create another person
```

You are not creating another person, despite you are just editing the properties of the `p` instance of `Person` class. So, when you are deleting Isak:

```
p.delete("Isak")
```

there are no Isak already, he was renamed to Sanne.

To solve this problem you should create two separate instances of Person:

```
var p1 = Persons()
var p2 = Persons()
p1.create("Isak", 11, "Boy")
p2.create("Sanne", 7, "Girl") // Here I create another instance of person
p1.delete("Isak")
```

At this state you have two persons: Sanne and Isak that you have just deleted and Sanne is still existing and is accessible.

If you want to use a single instance to hold all of your persons use this:

```
class Person {
var oldName = ""
var oldAge = 0
var oldGender = ""
var name = ""
var age = 0
var gender = ""

func create(_ name:String, _ age:Int, _ gender:String) -> String {

    if(age > 100) {
        print("Can't create a person with an age that is over 100!")

        return "Not created!"
    }

    if(gender == "Boy" || gender == "Girl") {

    }
    else {
        print("Gender has to be a girl or a boy!")

        return "Not created!"
    }
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.gender = gender

    self.oldName = name
    self.oldAge = age
    self.oldGender = gender

    print("You just created a \(gender) called: '\(name)' with the age of: '\(age)'!")

    return "Created!"
}

func modify(_ targetName:String, _ newName:String, _ newAge:Int, _ newGender:String) -> String {

    if(age > 100) {
        print("Can't modify a person with an age that is over 100!")
        return "Not modified!"
    }

    if(gender == "Boy" || gender == "Girl") {

    }
    else {
        print("Gender has to be a girl or a boy!")
        return "Not modified!"
    }

    if(targetName != "" && targetName == self.name) {
        self.name = newName
        self.age = newAge
        self.gender = newGender

        print("You just changed \(oldName)'s gender from: \(oldGender) to: \(gender), \(oldName)'s name from: \(oldName) to: \(name) and \(oldName)'s age from: \(oldAge) to: \(age)!")
    }
    else {
        print("Please enter a valid target name or create one!")
    }

    return "Modified!"
}

func delete() -> String {
    return "Deleted!"
}
}

class Persons {
var personsDictionary = [String: Person]()
}

var persons = Persons()
var p1 = Person()
var p2 = Person()

p1.create("Isak", 11, "Boy")
p2.create("Sanne", 7, "Girl")

persons.personsDictionary[p1.name] = p1
persons.personsDictionary[p2.name] = p2

persons.personsDictionary["Isak"]?.delete()
```

Here we have a Person class (one that you defined in your question but with slightly changed `delete()` method) and Persons class that have a [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) of `[String : Person]`. The key of dictionary is your person's name and value is this person.

When we create a person instance we store it in `personsDictionary` and than we can access every person in that dictionary by person's name and an Optional will be returned on which we can call all of your defined methods.

Comment: Yeah but I want to have one persons class variable. Thats why I made this post

Comment: It gives me an error saying: "Value of type 'Persons' has no member 'personsList'

Comment: @MopsiLikesFood yea, sorry, fixed that. Try it now

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a model object as a repository also.

You only need one simple model, for a simple model it is better to use a struct. This also gives you the initialiser for free

```
struct Person {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
    var gender = ""
}
```

Note: Better to use an enum for gender...

```
enum Gender {
    case male, female
}

struct Person {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
    var gender: Gender = .male
}
```

Then just use an array to manage a list

```
let simon = Person(name: "Simon", age: 20, gender: .male)
let isak = Person(name: "Isak", age: 11, gender: .male)

var people = [simon, isak]

print(people.count) // output: 2
people.remove(isak)
print(people.count) // output: 1

let sanne = Person(name: "Sanne", age: 7, gender: .female)
people.append(sanne)
```

I would suggest that you read through the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285) instantiation and arrays are quite basic. At the minimum read about classes, structs, instantiation and arrays.

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to do something like simon.modify (modify is a function I made)?

Comment: @MopsiLikesFood sure, just define functions that you want inside Person and call it when you need to.

Comment: Im sorry if I'm a noob but how do I do that? I made some functions inside of the persons class but how do I call them?

Comment: Why do you need to edit the item from a function? `var john = Person(name: "john", age: 20, gender .male)` `john.age = 30`. the way you are trying to do this with a single variable is wrong. a person cannot be multiple people. you need person objects and a list of `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the beginning of how I would go about it...

First the class to handle everything:

```
class Person {
    /// An enum for gender so that you can only ever use the permissable values.
    public enum Gender {
        case male
        case female
    }

    /// An enum for the results so there are defined values to check (you could add more specific errors).
    public enum Result {
        case success
        case failed(_: String)
    }

    /// A structure to hold the details of each person.
    struct PersonData {
        var name: String
        var age: UInt
        var gender: Gender
    }

    /// The internal list of people.
    private var personList: [String: PersonData] = [:]

    /// A function to create a person.
    func create(_ name: String, _ age: UInt, _ gender: Gender) -> Result {
        guard personList[name] == nil else {
            print ("Person already created!")

            return .failed("Person already created!")
        }

        guard age <= 100 else {
            print("Can't create a person with an age that is over 100!")

            return .failed("Cannot have age over 100!")
        }

        let person = PersonData(name: name, age: age, gender: gender)
        personList[name] = person

        print("You just created a \(gender) called: '\(name)' with the age of: '\(age)'!")

        return .success
    }

    /// A function to modify a persons details in the list.
    func modify(_ targetName: String, _ newName: String, _ newAge: UInt, _ newGender: Gender) -> Result {
        guard let person = personList[targetName] else {
            print ("Person not found in list!")

            return .failed("Person not found!")
        }

        guard personList[newName] == nil else {
            print ("Person already exists in list!")

            return .failed("Person already exist in the list!")
        }

        if newAge > 100 {
            print("Can't modify a person with an age that is over 100!")

            return .failed("Cannot modify a person with an ager over 100!")
        }

        let oldName = person.name
        let oldAge = person.age
        let oldGender = person.gender

        if targetName != newName {
            personList.removeValue(forKey: targetName)
        }
        personList[newName] = PersonData(name: newName, age: newAge, gender: newGender)

        print("You just changed \(oldName)'s gender from: \(oldGender) to: \(person.gender), \(oldName)'s name from: \(oldName) to: \(person.name) and \(oldName)'s age from: \(oldAge) to: \(person.age)!")

        return .success
    }

    /// A function to delete a person from the list.
    func delete(_ targetName:String) -> Result {
        guard let _ = personList[targetName] else {
            print ("Person not found in list!")

            return .failed("Person not found in list!")
        }

        personList.removeValue(forKey: targetName)

        print("Deleted: \(targetName)!")

        return .success
    }

    /// A test function to print out the current list of people.
    func printList() {
        for (name, person) in personList {
            print ("\(name) is \(person.gender) and age \(person.age)")
        }
    }

    /// Bonus to allow you to get a persons full details using something like person[name].
    subscript(name: String) -> PersonData? {
        return personList[name]
    }
}
```

Now here is how you use it:

```
let people = Person()

// Create Isak.
var result = people.create("Isak", 11, .male)

// Here is how to detail with the results.
switch result {
case .success:
    // Do something when successfully created.
    print ("Result = Success")
case .failed(let reason):
    // Do something when failed to create.
    print ("Result = \(reason)")
}

// Create Sanne
result = people.create("Sanne", 7, .female)

// Print the list to check they are in there.
people.printList()

// Delete Isak from the list.
result = people.delete("Isak")

// Change Sanne's name to New Sanne and age to 8.
result = people.modify("Sanne", "New Sanne", 8, .female)

// Print the list to check what's in there.
people.printList()

// Bonus showing how to get a persons full details.
if let personData = people["New Sanne"] {
    print ("\(personData.name) is \(personData.gender) and age \(personData.age)")
} else {
    print ("Not Found!")
}
```

The results should be:

```
You just created a male called: 'Isak' with the age of: '11'!
Result = Success
You just created a female called: 'Sanne' with the age of: '7'!
Sanne is female and age 7
Isak is male and age 11
Deleted: Isak!
You just changed Sanne's gender from: female to: female, Sanne's name from: Sanne to: Sanne and Sanne's age from: 7 to: 7!
New Sanne is female and age 8
New Sanne is female and age 8
```

I might also go further with it but that should be enough to get you started.

(Hopefully the comments explain what it going on but if not feel free to ask)